# How to fix wait for app to idle in XCUITest

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest, xcuitest

In my UI test, I sometimes get the `Wait for app to idle` message in the console. Usually, it's not that often, but now, it always appears and makes the test fails on my mac. This is what I have done so far:

1. Disabling/enabling animation didn't work
2. Disabling XCLogger that is used to log to a file didn't work
3. Disabling IQKeyboardManager didn't work

How do you get a trace of the main thread in UITest to see what's holding it? How do I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Does it always happen at the same place? The app must be doing something to cause XCUITest to think it's not ready to be worked on. If you're in touch with your developers, debugging with one of them is going to be your best bet.

Comment: @MikeCollins I think I know why. I have made helper functions to simplify tapping, inserting a string to a textfield, assert for existence, assert for non existence, etc. And at the start of each of those functions, I've added `app.activate()` to make sure the app is active. Silly me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, it's my mistake. I have made helper functions to simplify tapping, inserting a string to a textfield, assert for existence, assert for non existence, etc. And at the start of each of those functions, I've added `app.activate()` to make sure the app is active. So, it happened because I am too cautious.